# How to expand 2d array (30x20) to 36x60, which is contained in 620x480 2d array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

The start data: 2d array (620x480) is contained image, where shows human face, and 2d array (30x20) which is contained eye image. Face image includes eye image.

How I can expand eye image to 36x60 to include pixels from face image? Are there ready-made solutions?

Another similar task: the eye image have 37x27 size. How I can expand eye image to target(closest to 36x60) size, e.g. 39x65 i.e maintain the aspect ratio required before resizing and then resize to 36x60.

Code for testing (project is available by [reference](https://yadi.sk/d/Gg-NlNc-yM959Q)):

```
import dlib
import cv2 as cv
from imutils.face_utils import shape_to_np
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('res/model.dat')


frame = cv.imread('photo.jpg')
gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

img = frame.copy()
dets = detector(gray, 0)

for i, det in enumerate(dets):
    shape = shape_to_np(predictor(gray, det))
    shape_left_eye = shape[36:42]

    x, y, h, w = cv.boundingRect(shape_left_eye)
    cv.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + h, y + w), (0, 255, 0), 1)
    cv.imwrite('file.png', frame[y: y+w, x: x+h])
```

The image 42x13:
[image]

Comment: Could you add some images to explain what you want in more detail? As it currently stands, it's a bit confusing.

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda for testing you must install opencv and dlib libraries, and download trained model for dlib from https://github.com/davisking/dlib-models/blob/master/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda project for testing https://yadi.sk/d/Gg-NlNc-yM959Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part you can use `cv2.matchTemplate` to find the eye region in the face and then according to the size you want you can enlarge it. You can read more about it [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html).

FACE IMAGE USED

[image: face]

EYE IMAGE USED

[image: eye]

The size of eye I have (12, 32).

```
face = cv2.imread('face.jpg', 0)
eye = cv2.imread('eye.jpg', 0)
w, h = eye.shape[::-1]
res = cv2.matchTemplate(face,eye,cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
top_left = max_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
cv2.rectangle(face ,top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
cv2.imshow('image', face)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The result with this code is:

[image: matching eye on face]

Now I have the top left and bottom right co-ordinates of the eye that is matched where top_left = (112, 108) and bottom_right = (144, 120). Now to expand them to dimensions of 36x60 I simply subtract the required values from top_left and add the required values in bottom_right.

**EDIT 1**

The question has been edited which suggests that dlib has been used along with a model trained to perform left eye detection. Using the same code I obtained

[image: eye found]

After that as proposed above I find `top_left = (x,y)` and `bottom_right = (x+w, y+h)`.

Now if the eye size is smaller 36x60 then we just have to take the area around it to expand it to 36x60 otherwise we have to expand it as such that the aspect ratio is not disturbed and then resized and it cannot be hard coded. The full code used is:

```
import dlib
from imutils.face_utils import shape_to_np
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('res/model.dat')

face = cv2.imread('face.jpg', 0)
img = face.copy()
dets = detector(img, 0)
for i, det in enumerate(dets):
    shape = shape_to_np(predictor(img, det))
    shape_left_eye = shape[36:42]
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(shape_left_eye)
    cv2.rectangle(face, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 255), 1)
top_left = (x, y)
bottom_right = (x + w, y + h)
if w <= 36 and h <= 60:
    x = int((36 - w)/2)
    y = int((60 - h)/2) 
else:
    x1 = w - 36
    y1 = h - 60
    if x1 > y1:
        x = int((w % 3)/2)
        req = (w+x) * 5 / 3
        y = int((req - h)/2)
    else:
        y = int((h % 5)/2)
        req = (y+h) * 3 / 5
        x = int((req - w)/2)
top_left = (top_left[0] - x, top_left[1] - y)
bottom_right = (bottom_right[0] + x, bottom_right[1] + y)        
extracted = face[top_left[1]:bottom_right[1], top_left[0]:bottom_right[0]]
result = cv2.resize(extracted, (36, 60),  interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
cv2.imshow('image', face)
cv2.imshow('imag', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Which gives us a 36x60 region of the eye:

[image: eye extracted]

This takes care of the case when size of eye is smaller than 36x60. For the second case when the size of eye is larger than 36x60 region I used `face = cv2.resize(face, None, fx=4, fy=4, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)`. The result was:

[image: eye extracted 2]

The size of eye detected is (95, 33) and the extracted region is (97, 159) which is very close to the aspect ration of 3:5 before resizing which also satisfies that second task.

Comment: I just now saw your edit. Is there anything you want me to edit in my answer or solve the question using dlib?

Comment: I need this to work with the videostream. That parameters of extension are able to calculate dynamically. In each frame different coordinates of eye. Also, if I have size of eye, which go out boundaries, I must calculate the size more than 36x60, and then to resize to 36x60.

Comment: can the eye of size be anytime greater than 36x60?

Comment: Sometimes yes. Eg 37x27, in this case need to extend to closest size in relation 36x60 (in this specific case to 39x65, append a 3/5  add to 36x60)

Comment: is it fine now? @millka_15